# mysql select numeric is wrong, ignoring what's after the numeric value

Tags: mysql

Recently i was trying to **query** this

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`  WHERE `id` = '1a6' ORDER BY `date_created` DESC
```

but mysql is returning the row with ID = 1, it treated it as

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`  WHERE `id` = '1' ORDER BY `date_created` DESC
```

i was trying to check for no items found but apparently mysql returned that row which is wrong.

the ID is primary and AI, so what's the solution to make that query STRICT only to what's withing the quotes, it's like mysql is ignoring what's after the numeric value in the query.

Comment: In addition to everything else, if you are selecting single (or no) rows by their primary key, then it makes no sense to use an `ORDER BY` clause.  It cannot help you, but it could hurt (a little).

Comment: @JohnBollinger i'm curious, would you explain that please?

Comment: if your `WHERE` predicate necessarily allows at most one row -- because, for instance, it specifies an exact value of a `UNIQUE` combination of result columns -- then the order of those zero or one rows is irrelevant.  Specifying `ORDER BY` cannot have any effect on the result set in that case.  Potentially, however, it could cause a worse query plan to be chosen, and it certainly must require slightly longer for MySQL to parse and evaluate the query text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ID is autoincrement ("AI") then it must be numeric.  You should not quote its values as if they were strings.  If 1a6 is supposed to be a hexadecimal literal, however, then you omitted the leading `X`:

```
WHERE `ID` = X'1a6'
```

Comment: The forms `x'1a6'` (lowercase 'x') and `0x1a6` should also work.

Comment: didn't work when i tried it, but anyway is that secure, without quotes? cuz this should throw a mysql error which is not what i want, i want to give 0 rows found not an error

Comment: Just slapping untrusted input between quotes does not produce security.  Anyway, if your column is of numeric type then you should compare its values with *numbers*. The literal '1a6' is a string, not a number, and how MySQL deals with that is its own affair.

Comment: i see that it's not big deal, cuz i just tested it on facebook to add a character after a numeric and it ignored it as well

Comment: How are you running this query?  Using the mysql client directly, or via some programming language API?  If the latter then post the actual code.  The query you think you are running may not be the one you are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "LIKE" operator ...

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`  WHERE `id` LIKE '1a6' ORDER BY `date_created` DESC
```

Comment: wouldn't that slow down the query?, i was trying to find what's gonna happen if i put a wrong value, surprisingly it got the row with id 1

Comment: Yes it is an bit more slow but If the id column is numeric you must validate that the value is numeric before pass it to the query

Comment: `LIKE` is a *string* operator.  The best you could hope for when applying it to numeric values is that the values would be coerced to numeric strings, almost certainly in decimal format, for comparison to the pattern.  That would not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `posts`  WHERE `id` LIKE '1%' ORDER BY `date_created` DESC